# How to have jQuery code execute after DOM is completely loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC 5 and trying to get jQuery alert message when a form completely loads all its content. I have the following code that executes successfully and displays alert that time when a form has nothing displayed and totally blank, thanks

```
<script>
   alert("Registered Successfully");
</script>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "jquery alert message", it's just plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in document.ready:

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        alert("Registered Successfully");
    });
</script>
```

Or, use the shorthand:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
         alert("Registered Successfully");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank for reply. I did not understand why it should have to write under jquery function and what is difference between ur and my code? Will ur code runs when page is actually loaded? Thanks

Comment: both of the functions in my answer are telling the browser "Don't run this code until the DOM is completely loaded."  So you don't have to worry about the script firing before the elements are rendered.  If this answer was useful for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of these:
- Put your script at the end of the page.
- Write your code in `$(function() { });`or `$( document ).ready(function() { }`
- Write your code in `$(window).load()` to wait for all content including images.
- Without jQuery:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
```

Comment: Even if your script is "physically" at the end of the page, couldn't your DOM still be loading when it fires?

Comment: @stan at least all html will be loaded in this case, if you want to wait for images as well to get loaded before firing it you should use $(window).load()

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation that is even shorter:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        alert("Registered Successfully");
    });
</script>
```